# Why is "Carbon can form many compounds with long carbon chains" not correctly explained by "Carbon atoms can share electrons with one another"?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> Why is "Carbon can form many compounds with long carbon chains" not correctly explained by "Carbon atoms can share electrons with one another"?

I am a high school student just started learning organic chemistry and the above was a problem from a past public exam in my city. It is obvious that both statements are true but the answer key says that the later is not a correct explanation to the first. However, what I found on the Internet told me that the fact that carbon can form many compounds with long carbon chains is indeed due to the fact that they can form very covalent bonds with themselves. So what is wrong about the explanation?

Comment: Nearly all atoms can share electrons with many other atoms. Carbon is not special in this regard.

Comment: @Ivan what will be the real explanation then?

Comment: These statements are only tangentially related. Do you know what "explanation" means?

Comment: If you're saying that A: "Carbon can share electrons" and B: "Carbon can form long chains" and that B is the explanation for A, then it definitely isn't. You can say A explains B, but not B explains A. Your question seems to indicate that you think B should explain A.

Comment: @TRC I meant the opposite.

Comment: Somehow it is "that it can share electron with more others, up to four".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the prompt and turn it into a single sentence:

> Carbon atoms can share electrons with one another, therefore carbon can form many compounds with long carbon chains.

Now you can try this for other elements to see whether there is a cause and effect.

> Fluorine atoms can share electrons with one another, therefore fluorine can form many compounds with long fluorine chains (?)

The first part is true, e.g. $\ce{F2}$, but the second part is not true. You might say that fluorine is a bad example because it usually just makes one bond when forming molecules.

> Oxygen atoms can share electrons with one another, therefore Oxygen can form many compounds with long oxygen chains (?)

The first part is true, e.g. $\ce{O2}$ or ozone, but the second part is not true. Oxygen in molecules often makes two single bonds, so if that were the only requirement, it should make long oxygen chains but it does not.

> Nitrogen atoms can share electrons with one another, therefore nirogen can form many compounds with long nitrogen chains (?)

The first part is true, e.g. $\ce{N#N}$ or $\ce{H2N-NH2}$, but the second part is not true. Nitrogen in molecules often makes three single bonds, so if that were the only requirement, it should make long nitrogen chains (or even networks) but it does not.

We can go from carbon down the group to silicon, and still no long chains:

> The silanes ($\ce{Si_nH_{2n+2}}$) are less thermally stable than alkanes ($\ce{C_nH_{2n+2}}$). They tend to undergo dehydrogenation, yielding hydrogen and polysilanes. For this reason, the isolation of silanes higher than heptasilane has proved difficult.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_silicon-hydrogen_compounds

So what is wrong with the cause-effect relationship is that there are counter-examples where statement 2 ("long chains") does not follow from statement 1 ("share electrons"). There must be some other requirements for long chains of the same element, and it must be quite restrictive because carbon seems to be the only element making those chains, at least under our current terrestial conditions.